# how to select next item of wxlistbox in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am making a music player in python/wxpython. I have a listbox with all the songs, and the music player plays the selected song. I am now trying to make a "next button" to select the next item in the listbox and play it. How would I go about doing that? Is there something like GetNextString() or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to my knowledge. Just keep track of the currently selected item's placement in the list and update it by incrementing or decrementing it.